# How do I print the index of the maximum and minimum values?

Tags: c, arrays, max, min, function-definition

The following code prints the maximum and minimum value. How do I go about printing the index of those values rather than the values themselves?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr1[100];
    int i, mx, mn, n;   

       printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
       scanf("%d",&n);

       printf("Input %d elements in the array :\n",n);
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
          printf("element - %d : ",i);
          scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
        }


    mx = arr1[0];
    mn = arr1[0];

    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]>mx)
        {
            mx = arr1[i];
        }


        if(arr1[i]<mn)
        {
            mn = arr1[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum element is : %d\n", mx);
    printf("Minimum element is : %d\n\n", mn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just have two other variables (say `mxi` and `mni`) and set those to the 'current' `i` value in the same place as you are setting the `mx` and `mn` values.

Comment: Just add two more variable like `maxIndex` and `minIndex` for storing the values and put `maxIndex` inside your first of loop and `minIndex` inside your second if loop for storing values of index for maximum and minimum value and then use these variable . That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply save the index when you're updating `mx` respectively `mn`:

```
int max_index = 0;
int min_index = 0;

// ...

    if(arr1[i]>mx)
    {
        mx = arr1[i];
        max_index = i;
    }


    if(arr1[i]<mn)
    {
        mn = arr1[i];
        min_index = i;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the previous answer, you can use pointers and pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr1[100];
    int i, n;
    int *mn, *mx;

    printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Input %d elements in the array :\n",n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("element - %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }

    mx = &arr1[0];
    mn = &arr1[0];

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i] > *mx)
            mx = &arr1[i];

        if(arr1[i] < *mn)
            mn = &arr1[i];
    }

    printf("Maximum element is : %d (%d)\n", *mx, mx - arr1);
    printf("Minimum element is : %d (%d)\n\n", *mn, mn - arr1);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :5
Input 5 elements in the array :
element - 0 : 3
element - 1 : 2
element - 2 : 1
element - 3 : 5
element - 4 : 4
Maximum element is : 5 (3)
Minimum element is : 1 (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to change your code that to track the indices of minimum and maximum elements.

Just store in the variables `mx` and `mn` indices of correspondingly minimum and maximum elements instead of their values as for example.

```
mx = 0;
mn = 0;

for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
{
    if ( arr1[i] > arr1[mx] )
    {
        mx = i;
    }
    else if ( arr1[i] < mn )
    {
        mn = i;
    }
}
```

But I would like to point out that try always to write a more general code.

You could write a separate function that returns a pair of indices of maximum and minimum elements.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Pair { size_t min; size_t max; } 
minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    struct Pair minmax = { .min = 0, .max = 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < a[minmax.min] )
        {
            minmax.min = i;
        }
        else if ( a[minmax.max] < a[i] )
        {
            minmax.max = i;
        }
    }

    return minmax;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 1;

    printf( "Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int a[n];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % ( int )n;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    struct Pair minmax = minmax_element( a, n );

    printf( "The minimum value is %d at position %zu\n", a[minmax.min], minmax.min );
    printf( "The maximum value is %d at position %zu\n", a[minmax.max], minmax.max );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look for example like

```
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: 10
7 1 7 3 1 7 8 5 0 3 
The minimum value is 0 at position 8
The maximum value is 8 at position 6
```

Alternatively the function can be defined with two additional parameters: pointer to the index of minimum element and pointer to the index of maximum element.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n, size_t *min, size_t *max )
{
    *min = 0;
    *max = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < a[*min] )
        {
            *min = i;
        }
        else if ( a[*max] < a[i] )
        {
            *max = i;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 1;

    printf( "Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int a[n];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % ( int )n;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t min, max;

    minmax_element( a, n, &min, &max );

    printf( "The minimum value is %d at position %zu\n", a[min], min );
    printf( "The maximum value is %d at position %zu\n", a[max], max );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: 10
2 0 4 2 4 3 0 9 1 0 
The minimum value is 0 at position 1
The maximum value is 9 at position 7
```